# How to create a trigger that resets values to zero after 30 days?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table 'users'. In that table there is a field balance whose datatype is **ENUM('Yes','No')**. Now I want to create a trigger that is fired when the balance is set to **"Yes"**. Also I want to reset the value of Balance to **NO** after 30 days.

I am using **PHP Codeigniter**. And I have a reseller table who has its own users. So Each reseller has some users.

> So when a reseller sets the balance of user to yes the trigger should
>   be fired and after 30 days should set user balance to NO

Also the balance of each user should be Reset uniquely. I mean one uses's balance is set to yes today and user-two balance is set to Yes tomorrow . So how will trigger know when to fire for that each specific user?

Comment: Can you use cron job?

Comment: CRON job would work well here.

Comment: But i dont know how to create a trigger for this @jagad89

Comment: Come on Rajan: You are opening several questions for the same task. I wrote a couple of ways to solve your problem and you don't take it.You need a little bit of standing.

Comment: @Joerg Thanks man that issue has been solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is

- Maintain a column like `updatedon`.
- Write a stored procedure to set `balance` to NO when `updatedon` is 30 days and `balance` is `YES`(according to your critaria)
- Run a Job daily to invoke the stored procedure(It will set only 30 days back updated records)

Comment: Srinvas can you write down a sample code for me please

Comment: Try to write mysql stored proc we'll help you. if you struck any where.

Answer (score 2):

In order to track date you need to keep a column on which user `updated_to_yes_date`. When ever user update that enum column to "Yes" you should set current date to `updated_to_yes_date`.

Now lets code the controller for cron job.

```
class Cronjob extends CI_Controller {

  function index() {
    // Get Date before 30 days.
    $today = new DateTime();
    $dateBefore30days = $today->modify('-30 days');

    $this->db->update('users',array('enumcolumn'=>'No'), array('enumcolumn'=>'Yes', 'updated_to_yes_date'=>date_format($dateBefore30days , 'Y-m-d'));
  }
}
```

I have not tested above controller but it will help you.

Now its time to set up cron job. You need to run this cron job every day. To know how to setup cron job on cPanel [CLICK HERE](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs)

Now we need to execute controller method from command line. For that go to codeignitor [Running via the CLI](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) document.

In our case it will be like

```
$ php index.php cronjob index
```

In many case we need to provide full path to index.php like

```
$ php /path/to/webroot/index.php cronjob index
```